# MySQL : data is not replicating

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I have setup master master as well as master slave replication with three MySQL servers. My setup is like this->

I have three servers A, B and C

```
A --> B = Master Slave
A --> C = Master Master
```

MySQL Version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Here master master replication between A and C, Master slave replication between A and B works fine.

The problem is If I insert row in C then its replicating with A but not with B (as A and B are setup as master slave data should replicate to B as well). But if I insert row in A then its replicating with B.

Here am I missing something, what causes this problem ? 
Any comments on this will be appreciated.

Regards
Juned Khan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the variable [log_slave_updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) on A, so that as it plays changes in its replication thread, it also logs those changes to its binary log. Only that way will B receive the same changes.

Comment: `mysql> set log_slave_updates=ON;
ERROR 1238 (HY000): Variable 'log_slave_updates' is a read only variable`
While changing the value.

Comment: Right, it's not a dynamic variable. You must change it in my.cnf and restart the MySQL service. Refer to the documentation I linked to.